# Swift: Result of dateFromString nil unexpectely

Tags: swift, nsdateformatter

I went through all related questions and tried all suggestions but it just didn't worked out for me:

```
 let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
 dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm"
 dateFormatter.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "en_US_POSIX")
 dateFormatter.dateStyle = .FullStyle
 let timestamp = dateFormatter.dateFromString("07.07.2015 19:07")
```

timestamp is nil....    :-(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the line with the NSDateFormatterStyle:

```
let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm"
dateFormatter.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "en_US_POSIX")
let timestamp = dateFormatter.dateFromString("07.07.2015 19:07")
```

This is because setting an `NSDateFormatterStyle` overrides `dateFormatter.dateFormat`, making the results nil when using both.

The solution is to not use `NSDateFormatterStyle` if you already have a `dateFormat`.